# M2.2 | Button that can add multiple individual products to the cart all at once?

Tags: magento2.2, addtocart, multiple-add-to-cart

In short, we are looking for the ability to have a customizable button (be it through js, small module or whatever) to where we can have a button that would infact add multiple individual products to the customers cart via one click of the button, i.e. adding Product A, Product B and Product C with one click, rather than clicking each Add to Cart button individually.

After some googling, we can't find this exact functionality anywhere and wonder if this is possible be it a basic js entry or via its own little module.

Comment: My AjaxButton module can do this - see the example here https://github.com/gaiterjones/Magento2_AjaxButton

Comment: @paj this is great!! Real quick, I removed the .example from the layout xml and am using `{{block class="Gaiterjones\AjaxButton\Block\AjaxButton" name="gj-ajaxbutton-addproductstocart" template="Gaiterjones_AjaxButton::ajaxbutton.phtml"}}` within a cms page, but it seems to just keep reloading the `hello world` button.. what am I missing? Thanks!!!